# How do I create a delegate for a .NET property?

Tags: c#, vb.net, delegates

I am trying to create a delegate (as a test) for:

```
Public Overridable ReadOnly Property PropertyName() As String
```

My intuitive attempt was declaring the delegate like this:

```
Public Delegate Function Test() As String
```

And instantiating like this:

```
Dim t As Test = AddressOf e.PropertyName
```

But this throws the error:

> Method 'Public Overridable ReadOnly Property PropertyName() As
>   String' does not have a signature
>   compatible with delegate 'Delegate
>   Function Test() As String'.

So because I was dealing with a property I tried this:

```
Public Delegate Property Test() As String
```

But this throws a compiler error.

So the question is, how do I make a delegate for a property?

---

See this link:

http://peisker.net/dotnet/propertydelegates.htm

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Re the problem using AddressOf - if you know the prop-name at compile time, you can (in C#, at least) use an anon-method / lambda:

```
Test t = delegate { return e.PropertyName; }; // C# 2.0
Test t = () => e.PropertyName; // C# 3.0
```

I'm not a VB expert, but reflector claims this is the same as:

```
Dim t As Test = Function 
    Return e.PropertyName
End Function
```

Does that work?

---

Original answer:

You create delegates for properties with `Delegate.CreateDelegate`; this can be open for any instance of the type, of fixed for a single instance - and can be for getter or setter; I'll give an example in C#...

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
class Foo
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        PropertyInfo prop = typeof(Foo).GetProperty("Bar");
        Foo foo = new Foo();

        // create an open "getter" delegate
        Func<Foo, string> getForAnyFoo = (Func<Foo, string>)
            Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<Foo, string>), null,
                prop.GetGetMethod());

        Func<string> getForFixedFoo = (Func<string>)
            Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<string>), foo,
                prop.GetGetMethod());

        Action<Foo,string> setForAnyFoo = (Action<Foo,string>)
            Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<Foo, string>), null,
                prop.GetSetMethod());

        Action<string> setForFixedFoo = (Action<string>)
            Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<string>), foo,
                prop.GetSetMethod());

        setForAnyFoo(foo, "abc");
        Console.WriteLine(getForAnyFoo(foo));
        setForFixedFoo("def");
        Console.WriteLine(getForFixedFoo());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - Im stuck in .NET 2.0 for a project in question and I'll see if something similar works and feedback here (otherwise could be why the elaborate solution I linked to came about)

Comment: It appears to work (haven't tested extensively) but I'm wondering if you can help with this problem.  I need to get the property without using a hard-coded string. Problem is, I need the PropertyInfo to get the get method and I can't get this from the property addressOf

Comment: Thanks for the update - unfortunately VB.NET doesn't support anonymous methods - I guess the only solution is to make a function wrapper for each property and create a delegate for that (pretty much what the reflector code is doing).

Comment: VB.NET supports lambda expressions (but they must return a value) - http://blogs.msdn.com/wriju/archive/2008/02/05/vb-net-9-0-lambda-expression.aspx

Comment: It should be noted that Lambdas didn't exist in VB until VB2008, and even then they were only single line until VB2010 I believe.

Comment: When you get the property infos with BindingFlags.NonPublic, you find the getter or setter by using GetGetMethod(true) and GetSetMethod(true), respectively. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16024006/how-do-i-look-up-the-internal-properties-of-a-c-sharp-class-protected-protecte

Answer (score 12):

I just create an helper with pretty good performance : 
http://thibaud60.blogspot.com/2010/10/fast-property-accessor-without-dynamic.html
It don't use IL / Emit approach and it is very fast !

**Edit by oscilatingcretin 2015/10/23**

The source contains some casing issues and peculiar `=""` that have to be removed.  Before link rot sets in, I thought I'd post a cleaned-up version of the source for easy copy pasta, as well as an example of how to use it.

**Revised source**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Tools.Reflection
{
    public interface IPropertyAccessor
    {
        PropertyInfo PropertyInfo { get; }
        object GetValue(object source);
        void SetValue(object source, object value);
    }

    public static class PropertyInfoHelper
    {
        private static ConcurrentDictionary<PropertyInfo, IPropertyAccessor> _cache =
            new ConcurrentDictionary<PropertyInfo, IPropertyAccessor>();

        public static IPropertyAccessor GetAccessor(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
        {
            IPropertyAccessor result = null;
            if (!_cache.TryGetValue(propertyInfo, out result))
            {
                result = CreateAccessor(propertyInfo);
                _cache.TryAdd(propertyInfo, result); ;
            }
            return result;
        }

        public static IPropertyAccessor CreateAccessor(PropertyInfo PropertyInfo)
        {
            var GenType = typeof(PropertyWrapper<,>)
                .MakeGenericType(PropertyInfo.DeclaringType, PropertyInfo.PropertyType);
            return (IPropertyAccessor)Activator.CreateInstance(GenType, PropertyInfo);
        }
    }

    internal class PropertyWrapper<TObject, TValue> : IPropertyAccessor where TObject : class
    {
        private Func<TObject, TValue> Getter;
        private Action<TObject, TValue> Setter;

        public PropertyWrapper(PropertyInfo PropertyInfo)
        {
            this.PropertyInfo = PropertyInfo;

            MethodInfo GetterInfo = PropertyInfo.GetGetMethod(true);
            MethodInfo SetterInfo = PropertyInfo.GetSetMethod(true);

            Getter = (Func<TObject, TValue>)Delegate.CreateDelegate
                    (typeof(Func<TObject, TValue>), GetterInfo);
            Setter = (Action<TObject, TValue>)Delegate.CreateDelegate
                    (typeof(Action<TObject, TValue>), SetterInfo);
        }

        object IPropertyAccessor.GetValue(object source)
        {
            return Getter(source as TObject);
        }

        void IPropertyAccessor.SetValue(object source, object value)
        {
            Setter(source as TObject, (TValue)value);
        }

        public PropertyInfo PropertyInfo { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

**Use it like this:**

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

MyClass e = new MyClass();
IPropertyAccessor[] Accessors = e.GetType().GetProperties()
    .Select(pi => PropertyInfoHelper.CreateAccessor(pi)).ToArray();

foreach (var Accessor in Accessors)
{
    Type pt = Accessor.PropertyInfo.PropertyType;
    if (pt == typeof(string))
        Accessor.SetValue(e, Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n").Substring(0, 9));
    else if (pt == typeof(int))
        Accessor.SetValue(e, new Random().Next(0, int.MaxValue));

    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}:{1}",
        Accessor.PropertyInfo.Name, Accessor.GetValue(e)));
}
```

Comment: This property accessor of yours is awesome!  I based my new application on your property accessor and after fixing some minor bugs, everything works like a charm.

Comment: In current state this is not very good answer for SO - and should be either comment or expanded... Based on (10K+) deleted question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33292378/for-generic-parameters question there is some chance that linked code requires reworking to be usable (and may not be copied to SO due to licensing concerns).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov The question you linked to has been deleted.  Also, expand more on licensing concerns.  The answerer linked to their blog where they provided a code example.  Sure, you don't know if it requires licensing to use, but how do you know that any code examples  posted to SE don't require licensing?

Comment: I'll also add that I've tested the code there and it's pretty dang fast.  It even rivals neck-and-neck with the expression tree method I've been using.  You do have to edit the code, though, to get it to work.  There are casing issues and also these peculiar `=""` that need to be removed.  I find it pretty impressive that this code still holds up 5 years later.

Comment: @oscilatingcretin - SO have very specific license for all content posted - http://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing - CC BY-SA 3.0, re-posting someone else content that was produced under different license is generally very problematic. I understand that most people don't care, but the issue is there anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a C#/.NET 2.0 version of [Marc Gravell's response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724143/how-do-i-create-a-delegate-for-a-net-property/724427#724427):

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

class Program
{
 private delegate void SetValue<T>(T value);
 private delegate T GetValue<T>();

 private class Foo
 {
  private string _bar;

  public string Bar
  {
   get { return _bar; }
   set { _bar = value; }
  }
 }

 static void Main()
 {
  Foo foo = new Foo();
  Type type = typeof (Foo);
  PropertyInfo property = type.GetProperty("Bar");

  // setter
  MethodInfo methodInfo = property.GetSetMethod();
  SetValue<string> setValue =
   (SetValue<string>) Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof (SetValue<string>), foo, methodInfo);
  setValue("abc");

  // getter
  methodInfo = property.GetGetMethod();
  GetValue<string> getValue =
   (GetValue<string>) Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof (GetValue<string>), foo, methodInfo);
  string myValue = getValue();

  // output results
  Console.WriteLine(myValue);
 }
}
```

Again, '**Delegate.CreateDelegate**' is what is fundamental to this example.

Answer (score 2):

This is good idea

```
Test t = () => e.PropertyName; // C# 3.0
```

But take care if your are doing something like this:

```
List<Func<int>> funcs = new List<Func<int>>();
foreach (var e in Collection)
   funcs.Add(new Func<int>(() => e.Property));
```

Calling this:

```
foreach(var f in funcs)
   f();
```

Will always return value of property of the **last** object in Collection

In this case you should call method:

```
foreach (var e in Collection)
   funcs.Add(new Func<int>(e.GetPropValue));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a C# example but all the types are the same:

First create the interface(delegate). Remember, a method that you attach to your delegate must return the same type, and take the same parameters as your delegate's declaration.
Don't define your delegate in the same scope as your event.

```
public delegate void delgJournalBaseModified();
```

Make an event based on the delegate:

```
public static class JournalBase {
    public static event delgJournalBaseModified evntJournalModified;
};
```

Define a method that can be tied to your event that has an interface identical to the delegate.

```
void UpdateEntryList()
{
}
```

Tie the method to the event. The method is called when the event is fired. You can tie as many methods to your event. I don't know the limit. It's probably something crazy.

```
 JournalBase.evntJournalModified += new delgJournalBaseModified(UpdateEntryList);
```

What happens here is the method is added as a callback for your event. When the event is fired, your method(s) will be called.

Next we make a method that will fire the event when called:

```
public static class JournalBase {
    public static  void JournalBase_Modified()
    {
    if (evntJournalModified != null)
        evntJournalModified();
    }
};
```

Then you simply call the method -- JournalBase_Modified() -- somewhere in your code and all methods tied to your event are called too, one after another.

Comment: I didn't vote you down but the question referred to properties

Comment: Yea... I see that after the fact. Thank you for not voting me down. It looks like I answered without checking the context of the question... Silly me.

Answer (score 0):

VB version:

```
Dim prop As PropertyInfo = GetType(foo).GetProperty("bar")
Dim foo1 As New foo

Dim getForAnyFoo As Func(Of foo, String) = TryCast([Delegate].CreateDelegate(GetType(Func(Of foo, String)), Nothing, prop.GetGetMethod()), Func(Of foo, String))

Dim setForAnyFoo As Action(Of foo, String) = TryCast([Delegate].CreateDelegate(GetType(Action(Of foo, String)), Nothing, prop.GetSetMethod()), Action(Of foo, String))

Dim getForFixedFoo As Func(Of String) = TryCast([Delegate].CreateDelegate(GetType(Func(Of String)), foo1, prop.GetGetMethod()), Func(Of String))

Dim setForFixedFoo As Action(Of String) = TryCast([Delegate].CreateDelegate(GetType(Action(Of String)), foo1, prop.GetSetMethod()), Action(Of String))

    setForAnyFoo(foo1, "abc")
    Debug.WriteLine(getForAnyFoo(foo1))

    setForFixedFoo("def")
    Debug.WriteLine(getForFixedFoo())
```