# How to adapt this answer to a non-generically-typed class?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, properties, lambda

I'd like to adapt [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/491486/963396) into an existing utility class of mine - just the `GetProperty` method. Thing is, my utility class is not generically-typed (i.e. the class declaration does not have a `<T>` parameter like `PropertyHelper` does), and I cannot add one for the time being.

In other words, I only want that `GetProperty` method to be generically-typed, not the whole class.

So what modifications do I need to make the method work? I've tried adding T to the list of generic types for that method:

```
public static PropertyInfo GetProperty<T, TValue>(Expression<Func<T, TValue>> selector)
```

But it gives me errors when I try doing the following:

```
PropertyInfo prop = MyUtilClass.GetProperty<Foo>(x => x.Bar);
```

Obviously, this is because `GetProperty` expects a `T` and a `TValue`...

I'd simply like to be able to call it like above. How?

Comment: You can't, basically. C# won't let you infer just one type argument. You'll have to have a generic type *somewhere*.

Comment: Not sure if any of this old code helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724143/how-do-i-create-a-delegate-for-a-net-property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may be off base on this one, but it seems like if you want the code:

```
PropertyInfo prop = MyUtilClass.GetProperty<Foo>(x => x.Bar);
```

to work (assuming you're trying to get property info about that "x.Bar"), you would just define your function as:

```
public static PropertyInfo GetProperty<T>(Expression<Func<T, Object>> selector)
```

and then from within your function you'd read the name of the member, as in

```
MemberExpression member = (MemberExpression)selector.Body;
String propertyName = member.Member.Name;
PropertyInfo info = typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName, BindingFlags.Public 
            |  BindingFlags.Instance)
return info;
```

Like I said, I may be off base, but that's what it seems like you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks. This seems like what I want. However, why change the internals of the method (the third code bit in your answer)? Is there something wrong with the answer I linked?

Comment: Actually, no you're fine. In fact I completely forgot you could get the property info data from the MemberExpression itself. Heh. Looks like I learned something too!