# Direct memory access to underlying field data

Tags: c#, pointers, unsafe

I'm looking for a way to avoid FieldInfo.Get/SetValue overhead, and access memory directly for a few select, known ahead of time, primitive types. (Most specifically, I'm looking to avoid any memory allocations in our custom serializer)

Basically, here's what the official way allows me to do:

```
System.Object o = someobject;
int inOut = 0;

var type = o.GetType();
var fieldInfos = type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
foreach (var fi in fieldInfos) {
    fi.SetValue(o, inOut);
    inOut = (int)fi.GetValue(o);
}
```

And here's roughly what I'd like to do:

```
foreach (var fi in fieldInfos) {
    fixed(int* ip = o.basePointer + fi.fieldOffset) {
        *p = inOut;
        inOut = *p;
    }
}
```

I would use this only for Int32, Single, and possibly bools. I'm primarily interested in getting this working on Mono, so if there's anything Mono specific available, that'd be fine.

Note: I'm well aware of the "you shouldn't be doing this", and "have you profiled it" etc. I know, and I have, which is why I'm looking into this. We have a very specific case, where we control all variables (and all code), but we would like it to work on any 'normal' class without requiring additional markup or explicit struct layout.

EDIT: I should point out that I'm not able to emit dynamic code to solve this. I'm ok with a solution requiring me to write and assemble IL up-front though.

Comment: Are you doing this to avoid wrapping your `Int32` in object?

Comment: Pointers have a type, you cannot escape that.  A bool* is *not* the same as an int*, that matters a great deal once you dereference the pointer.  Of course you don't know the type, if you did then you wouldn't have used Reflection.  Fuggedaboutit.

Comment: @HansPassant Of course I know the type, I've already looked up and cached the types I care about _once_, using reflection for each new class encountered. What I'm left with now, is millions of Get/SetValue calls, all insisting on checking whether the value is _still_ not a literal, or static, or generic or my grandma and then passing my data through a short-lived box. I'm fully aware pointers have type, but give me _any_ pointer for starters and I'll use it correctly. We could debate whether this is a good approach for such a large amount of data, but changing that is currently not an option.

Comment: Dynamically generating code so the type lookup is only done once is a well established and universal technique.  With multiple ways to do it, CodeDom, Relection.Emit, Linq.Expression.  You should not be doing this, since it completely doesn't solve the problem, but you don't want to hear about it.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Partially to avoid the boxing, but also to avoid running the identical type checks millions of times.

Comment: @HansPassant I appreciate that, Hans, and I'd very much _like_ to use any standard codegen solution available. Unfortunately, this (also) needs to work in an environment where dynamic code generation is strictly forbidden, so the option just isn't available to me.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm well aware of the "you shouldn't be doing this"

That is good - I'll skip this part of the explanation then, and go straight to a way of accessing fields that avoids memory allocation, while staying within the limits of managed code.

You can use LINQ expressions to construct a `Func<ObjType,int>` for a getter and `Action<ObjType,int>` for a setter. Calling these functors would let you get or set `int` fields as if you were accessing their methods directly.

Here is how you can make a wrapper-free getter:

```
public class Test
{
    public int myfield;
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Make a parameter expression to represent the object
        var argExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Test), "a");
        // Get the field of your object (the same way as in your first example)
        var field = typeof(Test).GetField("myfield", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        // Make an expression accessing the field from the parameter
        var fieldExpr = Expression.Field(argExpr, field);
        // Compile the expression into a functor
        var getter = (Func<Test,int>)Expression.Lambda(fieldExpr, argExpr).Compile();
        // Construct a test object
        var tmp = new Test {myfield = 123};
        // Use a wrapper to avoid "boxing"/"unboxing" of "GetValue"
        int res = getter(tmp);
        Console.WriteLine("Res={0}", res);
    }
}
```

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/sHzAz5)

Construct the setter in a similar way, using one more parameter of type `int`, and [`Expression.Assign`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268005%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The resultant lambda will compile into an `Action<Test,int>` rather than `Func<Test,int>`, because setters do not return value.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Although technically a correct answer to my question, I am, unfortunately, not able to emit code dynamically to solve this problem. Do you recon I would be able to disassemble this solution and write it up front in plain IL, or are there elements in there that would make that approach impossible?

Comment: @tbone An IL-based solution would need to produce code dynamically as well. You don't even have to disassemble generated code. However, the code would need to generate that method dynamically anyway, because the type being serialized is not known at compile time.

Comment: I see what you're saying. I had forgotten that ldfld actually needs to know the type at assembly time, I was thinking I could pass the field info as an argument. I'm leaning towards just implementing your solution on the targets that _do_ allow dynamic codegen, and leaving it alone for the others.

Answer (score 0):

You say, that you can't use dynamic code generation. Here are some other ideas:

1. If you can work with properties instead of fields, create a delegate to the property getter (https://stackoverflow.com/a/724427).
2. Generate IL code for your serializer at build time. Compile that into an assembly that you can load at runtime. Just generate accessor code for each and every field. I think you can access private members in IL when FullTrust and SkipVerification permissions are present.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. We already do pretty much the same thing as you linked for properties. And I'm reluctant to add a new, large build-step just for this optimization.