# Does C# have pointers to members like in C++?

Tags: c#, pointers, pointer-to-member

In C++, you could write the following code:

```
int Animal::*pAge= &Animal::age;

Animal a;

a.*pAge = 50;
```

Is there similar functionality in C#?

**Edit:** To clarify, I am *not* asking about pointers. I am asking about "pointers to members", a feature found in C++ that is used with the `.*` and `->*` operators.

---

**Edit 2:** Here is an example of a use case for members to pointers.

Let's say we have the following class:

```
class Animal
{
    int age;
    int height;
    int weight;
    …
}
```

And let's say that we want to write methods that will find the average age/height/weight/etc. of all Animals in an array. We could then do this:

```
int averageAge(Animal[] animals)
{
    double average = 0;

    for (…)
        average += animals[i].age;

    return average/animals.length;
}

int averageHeight(Animal[] animals)
{
    //code here again
}

int averageWeight(Animal[] animals)
{
    //code here again
}
```

We would end up copying and pasting a lot of code here, and if our algorithm for finding the average changed, we would encounter a maintenance nightmare. Thus, **we want an abstraction of this process for any member**. Consider something like this:

```
int averageAttribute(Animal[] animals, Func<Animal, int> getter)
{
    double average = 0;

    for (…)
        average += getter(animals[i]);

    return average/animals.length;
}
```

which we could then call with

```
averageAttribute(animals, (animal) => animal.age);
```

or something similar. However, **using delegates is slower than it has to be**; we are using an entire function just to return the value at a certain location in the `Animal` struct. In C++, members to pointers allow you to do pointer math (not the right term but I can't think of a better term) on structs. Just as you can say

```
int p_fourthAnimal = 3;

(animals + p_fourthAnimal)*
```

to get the value so many bytes ahead of the pointer stored in the variable `animals`, in C++, you could say

```
int Animal::* p_age = &Animal::age;

animal.*p_age //(animal + [the appropriate offset])*
```

to get the value so many bytes ahead of the pointer stored in the variable `animal`; conceptually, the compiler will turn `animal.*p_age` into `(animal + [the appropriate offset])*`. Thus, we could declare our `averageAttribute` as this instead:

```
int averageAttribute(Animal[] animals, Animal::* member)
{
    double average = 0;

    for (…)
        average += animals[i].*member; //(animals[i] + [offset])*

    return average/animals.length;
}
```

which we could then call with

```
averageAttribute(animals, &Animal::age);
```

In summary, pointers to members allow you to abstract a method such as our `averageAttribute` to all members of a struct without having to copy and paste code. **While a delegate can achieve the same functionality, it is a rather inefficient way to get a member of a struct if you know you do not actually need the freedom allotted to you by a function**, and there could even be edge use cases in which a delegate does not suffice, but I could not give any examples of such use cases. Does C# have similar functionality?

Comment: sure, references. Have a look at `ref`-keyword. However you won´t need that to set the property of an `Animal`, just use `a.Age = 50`.

Comment: When you see something referring to a reference type (a type declared with class instead of struct), then you're dealing with the object through a pointer. In C++, everything is a value type by default. In C# everything is a reference type by default. a.Age is already accessing Age property through a reference to an instance of Animal

Comment: @HimBromBeere That was just sample code to demonstrate what I meant by "pointer to member".

Comment: Instead of describing what you think you need, describe what you want to do (what is your actual problem and where do you stuck, thinking that you need something like pointers to members in c++).

Comment: You can have a delegate, which is essentially a reference to a method. This is the closest I can think of right now.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724143/how-do-i-create-a-delegate-for-a-net-property. I don't see the point in C# to have the C++ feature you describe though. I would be interested in an explanation of the perks of such feature, if that's not going too far from the main topic

Comment: Useful in C++ doesn´t make it useful in C#. Why do you feel them useful? What specific **goal** are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @HimBromBeere Why would it not be useful in C#? Because there are other features that C# has that are better than members to pointers? If so, what are those features? I don't have a specific problem I am trying to solve at the moment, but I do know how useful pointers to members can be in C++, and I envision myself wanting the same functionality in C#. It could also be excessive for there to be a question for every single use case for members to pointers and how to achieve them in C#. Please correct me if you disagree.

Comment: Depending on what you´re actually doing the equivalent feature may be completely different. That´s why we need to know what **specifically** you´re trying to achieve. You already got some features that do similar things in the comments. However - as I alrlready said - there´s no 1:1-relation between language-features. You may have to re-structure your code a bit depending on the usecase.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Okay, I have added a use case. Is it thorough enough that one can comment on possible parallels in C#?

Comment: Well, for the first example you may use delegates as suggested in the comments. The seond one is something I don´t know, because I´ve seldom the need to know how many bytes are consumed by an instance (remember: in a managed language GC releases the memory for you quite decently).

Comment: @HimBromBeere Forgive me if it's a stupid question, but what do you mean by "first" and "second" example?

Comment: The one with the averages. In C# you may do this: `Average(animals, x => x.Age)` or `Average(animals, x => x.Height)`. The second is the sizeof-point. Did I miss something?

Comment: @HimBromBeere Oh duh, I forgot I wrote an example when I first asked my question. Yes, you could use delegates as I stated; however, an entire functor for retrieving the value of a struct's member is slow as I stated. Are delegates the only option in C#?

Comment: The only one I know. I´m not sure if those "functors" are really that slow or if this really matters much. Usually you have other problems than just a nano-second from such a member-access.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Sorry, I read what you said incorrectly. Yes, you may have missed something. I have removed the `sizeof` thing since it is probably a distraction. Are delegates not functors—classes with a single function generated by the compiler? My argument was that an entire function (which is what a delegate is as far as I understand) is unnecessary when all that is needed is some simple pointer math—math that can be achieved via pointers to members in C++.

Comment: @NetherGranite: If you think about sorting and comparing things there are things done at the JIT compile level to optimize method calls away. See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/04/18/performance-improvements-in-net-core-2-1/  where EqualityComparer<int>.Default.Equals(items[i], -1)) to compare two integers is not compiled into a wasteful method call but to some mov, cmp and a jump call. There are no pointer members in C# like this but if you know the offsets you can achieve similar things with pointers and unsafe code if you need to.

Comment: @AloisKraus I did wonder if the compiler was smart enough to boil away certain functor calls, how interesting. I wonder if that applies to all delegates that are just `(animal) => animal.age` or something similar. The deal with pointers to members is that the compiler turns those into the offsets for you; they *are* the offsets. `animal.*p_age` would translate to something like `(animal + [offset here])*`.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I replaced all mentions of "functor" with "delegate" and "function" to use C# terms. I may not even have been using "functor" correctly in the first place. Hopefully it makes more sense now.

Comment: @NetherGranite  From your perspective Garbage collection can be unnecessary to, when you can manually deallocate memory in c++. I don't understand the point of this discussion here. If you want to know details of how CLR, JIT compiler and how other stuff works, you can always read documentation to find it out.

Comment: If I understand correctly this is a pointer to a whatever member of the class (Animal in your example)?

Comment: @SeM To be honest, I'm not sure how what you said was related to what has been said. Where did garbage collection come in? With regard to the compiler, Alois mentioned an optimization that boils simple delegates away, something very relevant to this question since the functionality of members to pointers can be achieved with simple delegates but delegates are entire function calls and thus much slower.

Comment: @Phate01 Just as "arrays" are contiguous blocks of memory, so are structs. Let's say you knew the address of an `Animal` stored in the variable `animal`. If you knew that its `age` lied exactly 6 bytes ahead of the address `animal`, then you could then theoretically said something like `(animal + 6)*` to get the age. It's the same concept as arrays; if you know the address of the first element of an "array" of `Animal`s stored in the variable `arr`, if you know that the third element sits 3 bytes from the first element, you can say `(arr + 3)*`. (Note that the pointer math is obviously wrong.)

Comment: `Func` and `delegate` are the common solutions here. They may or may not be as performant as C++ - but they are the standard way to solve the issue.

Comment: @NetherGranite: No delegate calls wont go away because they are something which allows to change the call destination at runtime. The compiler could only optimize the ones away which can be proven to never change. But in that case you would simply use a method call anyway.

Comment: did someone actually compare the execution speed? I doubt that the hacky c++ approach is an advantage at all

Comment: Check out `inline` functions in F#. It's possible the compiler would optimize the function away completely, ending up with basically just pointer arithmetic in the assembly code. I haven't checked, but it should be doable.

Comment: @FalcoAlexander What made it hacky? The fact that you don't recognize it? No software developer familiar with pointers to members would look at that code and think it is "hacky"; that use is the very point of pointers to members. Can you clarify? If anything, writing an entire class and then instantiating an object and then passing that object to the average function (i.e. using delegates or function objects in general to solve this specific problem) is hacky.

Comment: @NetherGranite it seems you are not really interested in a solution, but are splittings words and obviously more like to discuss than develop. I'd find it useful to compare some benchmarks that show the advantage of pointer access, but I've no c++ workload installed. in 99% I'm glad I don't need to deal with pointers as when I was coding in 68k assembler 35 years ago

Comment: @FalcoAlexander I am interested in an answer to this question. The answer to this question appears to be "delegates are the *the* way to achieve this functionality", but no one has said this with authority; people have only said that delegates are *a* way to achieve this functionality, leaving open the possibility for other solutions. Also, how am I splitting words? Are you talking about "hacky"? I asked you what you meant by "hacky". You clearly meant something by it, and I was wondering what, but it did sound to me as though you called it "hacky" simply because you hadn't seen it before.

Comment: @NetherGranite I edited my answer to add some unsafe c# code that you may look for?! if that really is, what you looked for, I simply googled "c# member pointers"

Comment: @FalcoAlexander No, that was not what I was looking for. That is not related to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As other people have commented here, delegates are the way to achieve this in C#.

> While a delegate can achieve the same functionality, it is a rather
>   inefficient way to get a member of a struct if you know you do not
>   actually need the freedom allotted to you by a function

It depends how the compiler and runtime implement that delegate. They could very well see that this is a trivial function and optimize the call away, like they do for trivial getters and setters. In F# for instance you can achieve this:

```
type Animal = { Age : int }

let getAge (animal:Animal) =
    animal.Age

let inline average (prop:Animal->int) (animals:Animal[]) =
    let mutable avg = 0.
    for animal in animals do
        avg <- avg + float(prop(animal)) // no function call in the assembly here when calling averageAge
    avg / (float(animals.Length))

let averageAge = average getAge
```

Comment: Thanks! You not only answered the question clearly but also hit every point of the discussion that has resulted from the question, and *then* on top of that listed an alternative with an example. It's very interesting that F# allows you to explicitly ask for inlining.

Comment: `inline` also gives you some of the power of C++ templates, as you can make them generic and still access object members directly (not via an interface) with `member constraints`. So you can add whatever two things that support `'op_Addition'` for instance, which is impossible without going through an interface or delegate in C#.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the same behaviour using delegates but that's not the same thing as delegates are pointers to functions in C++. What you're trying to achieve is possible in C# but not in the way you're doing in C++.

I think about a solution using `Func`:

```
public class Animal
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
    public double Weight { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public static double AverageAttributeDelegates(List<Animal> animals, Func<Animal, int> getter)
    {
        double average = 0;

        foreach(Animal animal in animals)
        {
            average += getter(animal);
        }

        return average/animals.Count;
    }
}
List<Animal> animals = new List<Animal> { new Animal { Age = 1, Height = 2, Weight = 2.5, Name = "a" }, new Animal { Age = 3, Height = 1, Weight = 3.5, Name = "b" } };
Animal.AverageAttributeDelegates(animals, x => x.Age); //2
Animal.AverageAttributeDelegates(animals, x => x.Height); //1.5
```

It's working but you are bound to the `int` type of the property since the func is declared as `Func<Animal, int>`. You could set to `object` and handle the cast:

```
public static double AverageAttributeDelegates2(List<Animal> animals, Func<Animal, object> getter)
{
    double average = 0;

    foreach(Animal animal in animals)
    {
        int value = 0;
        object rawValue = getter(animal);
        try
        {
            //Handle the cast of the value
            value = Convert.ToInt32(rawValue);
            average += value;
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {}
    }

    return average/animals.Count;
}
```

Example:

```
Animal.AverageAttributeDelegates2(animals, x => x.Height).Dump(); //1.5
Animal.AverageAttributeDelegates2(animals, x => x.Weight).Dump(); //3
Animal.AverageAttributeDelegates2(animals, x => x.Name).Dump(); //0
```

Comment: Forgive me if it is obvious, but how is this different from the solution I described? From what I can see, they are identical. Also, what is the benefit of having the `getter` return `object`s instead of `int`s?

Comment: @NetherGranite object makes you use any type of properties, with int you can pass to the method only int properties

Comment: Oh, I see. Yes, that would definitely be useful in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

no, c# doesn't have a feature to point into (reference) object's members the way c++ does.

but why?
A pointer is considered unsafe. And even in unsafe area you cannot point to a reference or to a struct that contains references, because an object reference can be garbage collected even if a pointer is pointing to it. The garbage collector does not keep track of whether an object is being pointed to by any pointer types.

- you mentioned a lot of duplicate code is used to implement it the non-pointer way, which isn't true.
- Speed depends on how well the JIT compiles it, but you didn't test?
- if you really run into performance problems, you need to think about your data structures and less about a certain way to access members.

If think the amount of comments under your Q shows, that you did not really hit a commonly accepted drawback of c#

```
var Animals = new Animal[100];
 //fill array

var AvgAnimal = new Animal() {
    age = (int)Animals.Average(a => a.age ),
    height = (int)Animals.Average(a => a.height),
    weight = (int)Animals.Average(a => a.weight)
};
```

the `unsafe` area of c# serves [some ways](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/how-to-access-a-member-with-a-pointer) access members by pointer, but only to value types like single structs and not for an array of structs.

```
struct CoOrds
{
public int x;
public int y;
}

class AccessMembers
{
static void Main() 
{
    CoOrds home;

    unsafe 
    {
        CoOrds* p = &home;
        p->x = 25;
        p->y = 12;

        System.Console.WriteLine("The coordinates are: x={0}, y={1}", p->x, p->y );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Where did I say a lot of duplicate code is used to implement it the C# way? Also, I listed the solution you described above, claiming that *it* was slower than pointers to members since it requires entire function calls. Furthermore, I assume that a function call and a member access is slower than just runtime-defined member access without seeing test results, but if you would like to argue that this is not the case, I am all ears.

Comment: @NetherGranite check your Q: "We would end up copying and pasting a lot of code here, and if our algorithm for finding the average changed, we would encounter a maintenance nightmare"

Comment: You may have read it incorrectly. That portion of the example had nothing to do with C#; it would apply to any language. I then proceeded to suggest using delegates like you did above, which is something you *would* have to do in C# (and a few other langues like Java).

Comment: Oh, and I should add that the comments under the question actually show that pointers to members are not something C# developers are even aware of. Clearly they show that this is not a commonly accepted drawback of C# like you said, but the only reason why that has been presented to me so far is that C# developers aren't even aware there are alternatives. There are most likely some who can say why C# does not have pointers to members, and I would love to hear from them.

Comment: ok, a certain reasons why pointers to members are not implemented or may be considered unsafe could help. but you did not ask for that...now it looks a bit like you try to troll around...

Comment: You're right; I did not ask for that. However, the discussion I and others have had related to this post has evolved into that. My original question still stands, and no one has yet to give an authoritative answer that isn't just a suggestion on how to achieve the functionality with another C# mechanism. What do you mean when  you say it looks like I like to troll around?