# Based on a list of class objects, how to create a list of valid property names?

Tags: c#, linq, select, properties

I have a `Data` class that looks like the following.

```
public class Data
{
    public string Dt1 { get; set; }
    public string Dt2 { get; set; }
    public string Dt3 { get; set; }
    public string Dt4 { get; set; }
    public string Dt5 { get; set; }
}
```

And a list of class objects of it, with following sample data.

```
var list = new List<Data>
{
    new Data() { Dt1 = "DtA", Dt2 = string.Empty, Dt3 = "-", Dt5 = "DtC" },
    new Data() { Dt1 = "DtB", Dt2 = string.Empty, Dt3 = string.Empty, Dt5 = "-" },
    new Data() { Dt1 = "DtC", Dt2 = "-", Dt5 = "-" },
    new Data() { Dt1 = "DtD", Dt2 = string.Empty, Dt3 = "DtX", Dt5 = string.Empty },
    new Data() { Dt1 = "DtE", Dt3 = "-" }
};
```

I have a list of 'invalid' strings, which are the following.

```
var invalid = new List<string>() { string.Empty, "-", null };
```

Now, I'd like to identify property names from the above list, which contain at least one *valid* string, and then create a `List<string>` with those property names. If we consider above sample data, you can see that,

- All `Dt1` values are valid.
- All `Dt2` values are invalid.
- `Dt3` has at least one valid value.
- `Dt4` is never assigned, therefore, all values are invalid.
- `Dt5` has at least one valid value.

So, my resulting list should be

> Dt1, Dt3, Dt5

My approach for this is to write a function that identify if there's at least one valid value in a string, and then check each property of the list using that.

```
public static bool IsDataValid(List<string> data, List<string> invalid)
{
    foreach (var item in data)
    {
        if (!invalid.Contains(item))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then,

```
var invalid = new List<string>() { string.Empty, "-", null };
var result = new List<string>();
if (IsDataValid(list.Select(x => x.Dt1).ToList(), invalid))
{
    result.Add("Dt1");
}
if (IsDataValid(list.Select(x => x.Dt2).ToList(), invalid))
{
    result.Add("Dt2");
}
if (IsDataValid(list.Select(x => x.Dt3).ToList(), invalid))
{
    result.Add("Dt3");
}
if (IsDataValid(list.Select(x => x.Dt4).ToList(), invalid))
{
    result.Add("Dt4");
}
if (IsDataValid(list.Select(x => x.Dt5).ToList(), invalid))
{
    result.Add("Dt5");
}
```

This works, sure, but it's a bit 'ugly' for my taste. Also, my actual `Data` class has 20+ properties, so I'd have to use 20 `if` statements, which again smells of bad design.

I was wondering if there's another way, particularly one where I don't have to 'hardcode' if statements. Something like the following where I can iterate the properties of the class and figure out which of them from the list are valid.

```
foreach (var prop in typeof(Data).GetProperties())
{
    // How do I do a `.Select()` here?
}
```

Comment: Not quite. I know how to get a list of properties of a class. My problem is that since the acquired property names will be `string`, I can't do something like `list.Select(x => x.(property name)`, because, that wouldn't obviously work.

Comment: Not 100% sure how you'd implement it, but this looks a lot like `IValidatable` that's widely used in MVC / with data annotations. Maybe you could use `IValidatable` here, or think about creating a custom version of it. You would have to have validation ruls and then `yield return` when you do your validation checks

Comment: Then is something like this what you want?  https://dotnetfiddle.net/TCx5HN  I whipped it up quickly, it could probably be made more efficient by replacing the LINQ query by a manual loop...

Comment: @dbc this looks promising. Let me take a closer look.

Comment: Sweet, it works perfect. I'll accept it if you post it as an answer.

Comment: @Sach - I sped it up a bit by replacing the LINQ query + `Distinct()` with a simple loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Type.GetProperties()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getproperties?view=netframework-4.8) to get all properties of your type, then use [`PropertyInfo.Name`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.memberinfo.name?view=netframework-4.8#System_Reflection_MemberInfo_Name), [`PropertyInfo.PropertyType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.propertytype?view=netframework-4.8#System_Reflection_PropertyInfo_PropertyType) and [`PropertyInfo.GetValue()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getvalue?view=netframework-4.8#System_Reflection_PropertyInfo_GetValue_System_Object_) to get the names and values of all string properties of each `Data` item in your collection. With that you can collect the names of all properties with at least one valid value as follows:

```
public static class ValidationExtensions
{
    public static ICollection<string> ValidProperties<TObject, TValue>(this IEnumerable<TObject> items, Predicate<TValue> isValid)
    {
        var properties = typeof(TObject).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
            .Where(p => typeof(TValue).IsAssignableFrom(p.PropertyType))
            .Where(p => p.CanRead && p.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0 && p.GetGetMethod() != null)
            .ToList();

        var set = new HashSet<string>();

        foreach (var i in items) // Only iterate through the items once.
            foreach (var p in properties)
            {
                if (set.Contains(p.Name)) // Do not call GetValue() if not necessary, it's expensive.
                    continue;
                if (isValid((TValue)p.GetValue(i)))
                    set.Add(p.Name);
            }

        // Return properties in order
        return properties.Select(p => p.Name).Where(n => set.Contains(n)).ToList();
    }
}
```

Notes:

- If performance is an issue, you might want to build a table of delegates for accessing the property values of a given type using `Delegate.CreateDelegate`, e.g. as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/724427/3744182) to *[How do I create a delegate for a .NET property?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/724143/3744182)*.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TCx5HN).

Comment: Thanks, this looks perfect!